# Insert blanks based on xml depth in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Need help in generating an XSL template for converting an XML file to text output. The XML file is as given below.

```html
<CP Txt="Text1">
 <CP Txt="ABC">
  <CP Txt="CDE">
   <CP Txt="EFG"/>
   <CP Txt="HIJ">
    <CP Txt="KLM"/>
    <CP Txt="NOP"/>
   </CP>
  </CP>
  <CP Txt="QRS">
   <CP Txt="TUV"/>
   <CP Txt="WXY"/>
   <CP Txt="Z01"/>
  </CP>
 </CP>
</CP>
```

Expected output is as below.

```html
Text1
   ABC
      CDE
 EFG
 HIJ
    KLM
    NOP
      QRS
 TUV
    WXY
    Z01
```

Any help or suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for version 2.0 please specify the version with question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*">
            <xsl:call-template name="tab">
                <xsl:with-param name="ancestor-count" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('', @Txt)"/><xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tab">
        <xsl:param name="ancestor-count"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $ancestor-count">
            <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**For XSLT 1.0 you can use this code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Tabs" select="'&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($Tabs, substring($Tabs, count(ancestor::*)+1))"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Txt"/><xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**NOTE:** You have to update variable Tabs by using tabs entities if your xml nesting is more.

Comment: See mentioned link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBth/30

Comment: Thanks @Amerndra for your help...I am looking at Version2.0 and have one more quick question. If the XML is in the format of 
<CP Checked = 'Y' Txt="Text1">
    <CP Txt="ABC">
        <CP Checked = 'Y' Txt="CDE">
            <CP Txt="EFG"/>
            <CP Checked = 'Y'  Txt="HIJ">
                <CP Txt="KLM"/>
                <CP Checked = 'Y'  Txt="NOP"/>
            </CP>
        </CP>
        <CP Checked = 'Y' Txt="QRS">
            <CP Checked = 'Y' Txt="WXY"/>
        </CP>
    </CP>
</CP>
and we only need the nodes which have Checked = 'Y', then how will the xsl change.

Comment: then check the condition for attribute checked with its value = 'Y': https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBth/31

Comment: @AmerndraKumar can also take a look at another question that I have added. I have added the actual XML in question there. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901003/need-help-in-generating-text-output-from-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

You can test the depth of an element in the source tree using `count(ancestor::*)`.

In XPath 3.1 you can output `$n` spaces using `string-join((1 to $n)!" ")`.

In XPath 2.0 you can output `$n` spaces using a [for expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions) `string-join(for $i in (1 to $n) return ' ')`

If you only have XPath 1.0 available it's more difficult; I would use a variable `$spaces` containing a string of as many spaces as you will ever need, and then use `substring($spaces, 1, $n)`.

When asking for XSLT help, please always say which version you are using, since solutions using XSLT 2.0 or later are often much simpler.