# Need help in generating text output from XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, ancestor

Need help with building an XSL version 2.0 file in converting XML file to text output.

Below is the XML file. For all the elements that have field as "Checked = 'Y'" we need a "[X]" concatenated before the text output.

Tab spaces should be based on the level of ansestor-tags.

```html
<Review>
 <Assignment/>
 <Authorization/>
 <Criteria>
  <Components/>
  <OrganizationalPolicy/>
  <DecisionPoints/>
  <Notes/>
  <QualityIndicators/>
  <Responses>
   <Response CPID="AISD01590403010101" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD01590403010102" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD01590403010103" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD0159040301010401" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD01590403010104" Met="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD015904030101" Met="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD0159040301010402" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD0159040301010403" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD0159040301010404" Met="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD015904030101040401" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD015904030101040402" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD015904030101040403" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD015904030101040404" Checked="Y"/>
   <Response CPID="AISD0159040301010405" Checked="Y"/>
  </Responses>
  <QuestionsAsked/>
 </Criteria>
 <ReviewSummaryXML>
  <CP ID="AISD015901" Txt="(Symptom or finding within 24h)"/>
  <CP ID="AISD015902" Txt="(Excludes PO medications unless noted)">
   <CP ID="AISD015904" Txt="Select Day, One:">
    <CP ID="AISD01590401" Txt="Pre-op Day, One:"/>
    <CP ID="AISD01590402" Txt="Operative Day, One:"/>
    <CP ID="AISD01590403" Txt="Post-op Day 1, One:">
     <CP ID="AISD0159040301" Txt="OBSERVATION, One:">
      <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD015904030101" Txt="Responder, discharge expected today if clinically stable last 12h, All:">
       <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD01590403010101" Txt="Able to perform ADLs or return to baseline"/>
       <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD01590403010102" Txt="Pain controlled or manageable"/>
       <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD01590403010103" Txt="Tolerating PO or nutritional route established"/>
       <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD01590403010104" Txt="Complication or comorbidity, &gt;= One:">
        <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD0159040301010401" Txt="No complication or active comorbidity relevant to this episode of care"/>
        <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD0159040301010402" Txt="Arrhythmia controlled"/>
        <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD0159040301010403" Txt="Bleeding controlled or manageable"/>
        <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD0159040301010404" Txt="Recovered from anesthesia, All:">
         <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD015904030101040401" Txt="Stable level of consciousness"/>
         <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD015904030101040402" Txt="Mobility and coordination at baseline"/>
         <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD015904030101040403" Txt="Sensation intact"/>
         <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD015904030101040404" Txt="O2 sat &gt;= 92%(0.92) or within acceptable limits"/>
        </CP>
        <CP Checked="Y" ID="AISD0159040301010405" Txt="Passing urine without urinary retention"/>
        <CP ID="AISD0159040301010406" Txt="Postoperative vomiting resolved"/>
       </CP>
      </CP>
     </CP>
    </CP>
    <CP ID="AISD01590404" Txt="Post-op Day 2, One:"/>
    <CP ID="AISD01590405" Txt="Post-op Day 3, One:"/>
    <CP ID="AISD01590406" Txt="Post-op Day 4, One:"/>
    <CP ID="AISD01590407" Txt="Post-op Day 5, One:"/>
    <CP ID="AISD01590408" Txt="Post-op Day 6-10, One:"/>
    <CP ID="AISD01590409" Txt="Post-op Day 11, One:"/>
   </CP>
  </CP>
 </ReviewSummaryXML>
</Review>
```

Expected output is as given below.

```html
(Excludes PO medications unless noted)
 Select Day, One:
  Post-op Day 1, One
   OBSERVATION, One:
    [X] Responder, discharge expected today if clinically stable last 12h, All:
     [X] Able to perform ADLs or return to baseline
     [X] Pain controlled or manageable
     [X] Tolerating PO or nutritional route established
     [X] Complication or comorbidity, &gt;= One:
      [X] No complication or active comorbidity relevant to this episode of care
      [X] Arrhythmia controlled
      [X] Bleeding controlled or manageable
      [X] Recovered from anesthesia, All:
       [X] Stable level of consciousness
       [X] Mobility and coordination at baseline
       [X] Sensation intact
       [X] O2 sat &gt;= 92%(0.92) or within acceptable limits
        [X] Passing urine without urinary retention
```

Comment: What code do you have so far, please?

Comment: @AnyMoose this is what I have till now. http://xsltransform.net/aiwQ4n/1

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XSLT please? xsltransform.net is frequently unavailable.... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XSLT, you seem to be only selecting elements where `Checked` is "Y"

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*[@Checked='Y']">
```

So, all other elements are ignored. I think you should be selecting elements with a `Txt` attribute here:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*[@Txt]">
```

(And similarly for the count)

Then, to determine whether to show an "[X]" at the front, you can do this:

```
<xsl:if test="@Checked='Y'">[X] </xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="@Txt"/>
```

Or maybe this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(if (@Checked = 'Y') then '[X] ' else '', @Txt)"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="ReviewSummaryXML">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*[@Txt]">
            <xsl:call-template name="tab">
                <xsl:with-param name="ancestor-count" select="count(ancestor::*[@Txt])"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(if (@Checked = 'Y') then '[X] ' else '', @Txt)"/><xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tab">
        <xsl:param name="ancestor-count"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $ancestor-count">
            <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of `xsl:strip-space` too, to avoid excess whitespace being output before your text.

*EDIT* - In answer to your comment, if you only want to output elements where `@Checked` is "Y" or they have a descendant that has `@Checked` equal to "Y", add the condition `[descendant-or-self::*/@Checked='Y']` to the relevant expressions.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="ReviewSummaryXML">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*[@Txt][descendant-or-self::*/@Checked='Y']">
            <xsl:call-template name="tab">
                <xsl:with-param name="ancestor-count" select="count(ancestor::*[@Txt][descendant-or-self::*/@Checked='Y'])"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(if (@Checked = 'Y') then '[X] ' else '', @Txt)"/><xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tab">
        <xsl:param name="ancestor-count"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $ancestor-count">
            <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT 2:** If you want an XSLT 1.0 solution, try this....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="ReviewSummaryXML">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*[@Txt][descendant-or-self::*/@Checked='Y']">
            <xsl:call-template name="tab">
                <xsl:with-param name="ancestors" select="ancestor::*[@Txt][descendant-or-self::*/@Checked='Y']"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:if test="@Checked = 'Y'">[X] </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Txt"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tab">
        <xsl:param name="ancestors"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$ancestors">
            <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, @TImC, the above XSLT file is also generating all the nodes which don't have an at least one Checked='y'. We only need to get the ancestors of the ones where we have at least one child node has a parameter as Checked = 'Y'.

Comment: @naidunp - I've amended my answer with an example of how to achieve this.

Comment: when I am trying to add the XSLT file in XML notepad or microsoft's xslt parser it is giving me an error saying "Expected end of the expression, found 'to '. " How can we mitigate that.

Comment: This is an XSLT 2.0 solution. Any Mircosoft tool for XSLT is almost certainly XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks, @TimC is there a way we can achieve these functionalities to achieve the output.

Comment: I have edited my answer again, to include an XSLT 1.0 solution

Comment: So the template for the tab is not going to work for the XSLT1.0 solution correct.

Comment: I have amended the XSLT 1.0 solution in my answer to show how it can use a template for the tab instead.

Comment: Sorry, I just spotted an error in my XSLT 1.0 solution, which I have just corrected.